# Disabling submit button permanently if desired value is inserted into database - php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

the following update form updates data about the food preference of each user in a password protected area under some predefined answers of a questionnaire.

For example,

Question: what's you favorite food?

Answer:

1. Cheese
2. Meat
3. Salad

the submit button of the following form should be disabled permanently based on the predefined value of variable `$trigger` when the user submit it.

```
$trigger = '1';
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "formX")) { 
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE foodtable SET food_preference=%s, trigger=%s, WHERE food_id=%s",    
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['food_preference'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString(trim($trigger), "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['food_id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_XYZ, $XYZ);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $XYZ) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "preference.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
    exit ();
}
```

---

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="formX" id="formX">
<table align="center">
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">Update Food Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="food_name" value="" size="32" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
     <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="formX" />
     <input type="hidden" name="trigger" value="<?php echo "$trigger"; ?>" />
     </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update Food Name" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form>
```

how to perform it with pure php conditional statement? should i bring change in html form code too? any reference or suggestion shall be well appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

the following update form updates food preference of individual user in a password protected user area.

```
 $trigger = '1';  
//note: default value of $trigger= '0'; when user submits data using insert form primarily. when they update data using this update form the value changes to `1`

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "formX")) { 
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE foodtable SET food_name=%s, trigger=%s WHERE food_id=%s",    
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['food_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString(trim($trigger), "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['food_id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_XYZ, $XYZ);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $XYZ) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "preference.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
    exit ();
}
```

---

```
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="formX" id="formX">
<table align="center">
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">Update Food Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="food_name" value="" size="32" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
     <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="formX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="food_id" value="<?php echo $query['food_id']; ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="trigger" value="<?php echo "$trigger"; ?>" />
     </td>
     <td>
      < ?php 
        $disabled = "disabled";
        if (isset (which conditional statement shall disable the form permanently based on $trigger = '1'; ?)) {
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Update Food Name' " . $disabled . "/>";
        }else{
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Update Food Name'/>";
        } 
       ?>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form>
```

by the way, i use the following mysql syntax to get the column values for disabling the submit button:

```
$query = "SELECT food_id, food_name, trigger FROM foodtable WHERE food_id > 0 AND trigger = '1'";
```

---

whhich conditional php statement i should use to disable the form as indicated html portion of this edited post?

it can be solved in a lengthy way, but i was expecting a reasonable method.

if you feel that my question makes you clear enough, your reply shall be well appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, you should no trust the fact that the form is disabled. There are ways to enable it client-side. You should put some flag in database and check for it before running update query.

Comment: yes, i had the plan to do that. i was expecting reference or suggestion about the basic php syntax and modified html code (if applicable). however, i have edited my question for your convenience. thanks,

Comment: Could you post a query that **works**, which you use to get `$trigger` value on the page *after* the user submitted the form?

Comment: `$query = "SELECT food_id, food_name, trigger FROM foodtable WHERE food_id > 0 AND trigger = '1'";` brings all the data filtered by trigger value.

Comment: That's not what I meant. This is a query for ALL forms. Let's say we have ONE specific form. How do you know if it was or not submitted previously? Which id is unique for every form? food_id or which?

Comment: `food_id` is the primary key. thanks,

Comment: Well basically you need a way to differ two different forms. So that each form has some id associated with it. Say `form_id`. Then you can query database to see if the form is submitted. And the result of the query will then be the flag to disable or enable the submit button. Right now you don't tell me how you differ forms so I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way. Once user submits the form the flag is written into his session (however I would recommend storing this data in database, since session will be reset if he closes and then re-opens the browser; but this code should help you get started).

First of all, at start of the script you initialize the session:

```
session_start();
```

Then, before the update you check if he has not submitted the data already:

```
if ((!isset($_SESSION['has_submitted']) or !$_SESSION['has_submitted'])
    and (isset($_POST["MM_update"])) and ($_POST["MM_update"] == "formX")) {
```

And, of course, you need to set the flag after the update:

```
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $XYZ) or die(mysql_error());
$_SESSION['has_submitted'] = TRUE;
```

Finally, when you echo the submit button, you just check this flag and act accordingly:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update Food Name" <?php echo ((isset($_SESSION['has_submitted']) and $_SESSION['has_submitted']) ? 'disabled' : ''); ?> />
```

**Edit**

When user enters the page, you need to get the current `trigger` value:

```
$trigger = mysql_query("select trigger from foodtable where food_id=...");
```

Then you simply check the `$trigger` variable when the form is output or submitted (assuming user has somehow enabled the form):

if (!$trigger and (isset($_POST["MM_update"])) and ($_POST["MM_update"] == "formX"))

and

```
<input type="submit" value="Update Food Name" <?php echo ($trigger ? 'disabled' : ''); ?> />
```

Comment: in the example of my question, the submit button should be disabled permanently (session isn't applicable here at all) based on a conditional php syntax when the value of database column `trigger` shall be updated to `1` on form submit. anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @SilentPond why do you want to display the form then if only one user ever can submit it? Could you please clarify?

Comment: it's not right that one user can submit the form once only. please note that, the form we discuss about is an update form but not an insert form. in this case, the respective user can submit the form once only associated with one `primary id`. the user can resubmit this form after he shall insert new data into database through an insert form associated with another id that shall be incremented automatically. here we have to disable the submit button based on the value of database column `trigger` (variable value was defined as `$trigger = '1';`) using a conditional statement. any idea? thanks,

Comment: in the insert form default value `$trigger = '0';` . submission of update form changes that value to `1` in the database. the value `1` should be utilized with a conditional php statement in the respective webpage in order to disable the update form. i can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: @SilentPond Updated the answer. The only thing to edit is the way `food_id` is getting into the query. You didn't specify how you track different items.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect to get help when you don't post details of the problem.

Comment: Well, you need to look in error log to see what the errors are. Looking at the code you miss dots to the right and left of `$_SESSION[something_predefined_in_login_session]` which is a syntax error. Check php error logs to see other potential errors

Comment: unfortunately the syntax doesn't work, but i'm sure that we have to get the value of trigger for using it in the conditional statement. i use relational id and session based mysql statement to filter and track different items from two tables.

Comment: mysql syntax doesn't produce any error. everything works quite fine.

Comment: i have reedited my question. if you feel that my question makes you clear enough, your reply shall be well appreciated.